# Update mongodb record using objectID not working

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a route in a Flask application that updates an attribute of a specified record. The code I currently have isn't working so I must be doing something wrong but all the places I am looking, my code looks similar.

Take this Object:

`{"item": "Finish homework", "_id": {"$oid": "549548f93482984f399f9"}, "complete": false}`

I want to update "complete" to be True. Here is the code I currently have in my route:

```
todos.update({ "_id": todo_id }, { "$set": { "complete": "True" } })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What about `True` value try this: `{ "$set": { "complete": True } }`not string "True"

Comment: I tried that too and still not working

Comment: Figured it out. Had to use pymongo ObjectID and turn the ID I was using into a string

Answer (score 1):

Had to turn the todo_id into a string and use bson ObjectID

```
todos.update({ "_id": ObjectId(str(todo_id)) }, { "$set": { "complete": True } })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var myObj =   { $set: {name:  req.body.name , branch:  req.body.branch}};
        dbo.collection("my_std_table").update({"_id":  ObjectID(req.params.id)}, myObj, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 document updated");
            db.close();
            res.send(result);
        });
    });
```